# Vb.net application that use a SQL server database - An Undo command

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In some standart programs like Word or Excel for example , when I made some changes , even when I save the document , until it's not closed , I can go back and undo the changes step by step.

Is there any way to implement this feature , on a vb.net application that use a sql server database ?

Thank you !

Comment: like undo what is being saved in SQL server?

Comment: Until the application is open , I mean a general undo for every changes saved or not yet saved on database. The same logic as I have described for Word -With an word document.

Comment: There is slight problem - databases are usually in shared use. If you read data, you got 'apple' for example. Now you uptade it to 'orange', but in between someone has updated it to 'banana' already - what should your undo do then?

Comment: I have just an imagination how should it be ( I don't know if is possible ). But if I change from apple - to - orange , and someone change from orange - to banana , both these are saved somewhere as "Undo steps". So if I undo for the first time  from banana- return to orange , after from orange- return to apple . and no more undo because it's returned to initial value...... ? I

Comment: why don't you just update the record and save it back to it's initial value rather than undoing things which complicates everything that might cause the system to fail.

Comment: @MAC - The response is  another question : Why Word doesn't back to original value instead of undo step by step ? " I like the Word idea , so for what I'm asking if is there any way to implement .

Comment: The UnDo history is not saved to the doc or xl file.  If you reopen those files, the history is empty.  A different paradigm than a db record history and not mutually exclusivem

Answer (score -1):

The best idea here is to maintain logs. (Add, Edit, Delete logs for table).

And give options to user to 'Revert back to previous changes', he can then choose at what point in time he wants to revert to. You can show 'change history' for a record from log for that purpose.